# Spring does not rollback when "Executing identity-insert immediately"

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am having a problem with the Spring rollback transaction. I have a method which creates a new order inserting in several tables (`users`, `order`, `order_product`...). If there is an exception before method finishes the rollback is launched and the record in `order_product` is deleted but `users` record still remains. I would like to delete all records generated in my database. The `users id` field (primary key) is generated by Autoincrement in MySQL 5.6. and the primary key of `order_product` is two foreign keys.

User table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `new_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `allowed_newsletter` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  `lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lang` enum('en','de','fr','es') DEFAULT 'es',
  `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_EMAIL` (`email`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1092 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

order_product table:

```
CREATE TABLE `order_product` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `detail_json` longtext,
  `shipping_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_product_status` enum('PaymentPending','ShippingPending','Sent','Cancelled') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PaymentPending',
  `is_downloaded` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`order_id`),
  KEY `IDX_OP_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `IDX_OP_ORDER_ID` (`order_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_OP_ORDER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `order_customer` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_OP_PRODUCT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I'm using MySQL 5.6, Hibernate 4 and Spring 4.

Log file related:

```
[annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource(getTransactionAttribute:108)] Adding transactional method 'UsersDAOImpl.insertUser' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; 
[jpa.JpaTransactionManager(doGetTransaction:334)] Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@395dbec7] for JPA transaction
[jpa.JpaTransactionManager(handleExistingTransaction:476)] Participating in existing transaction
[spi.ActionQueue(addResolvedEntityInsertAction:213)] Executing identity-insert immediately
[hibernate.SQL(logStatement:104)] 
    insert 
    into
        users
        (allowed_newsletter, email, lang, lastname, name, new_email, phone) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2016-12-19 09:47:46,046 DEBUG (http-bio-8080-exec-3) [id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper(getGeneratedIdentity:93)] Natively generated identity: 1091
2016-12-19 09:47:46,047 DEBUG (http-bio-8080-exec-3) [spi.ActionQueue(addResolvedEntityInsertAction:213)] Executing identity-insert immediately
.....
... MORE INSERTs - SELECTs - etc ...
.....
[annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource(getTransactionAttribute:108)] Adding transactional method 'OrderProductServiceImpl.addNewOrderProduct' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
[jpa.JpaTransactionManager(doGetTransaction:334)] Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@395dbec7] for JPA transaction
[jpa.JpaTransactionManager(handleExistingTransaction:476)] Participating in existing transaction
[annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource(getTransactionAttribute:108)] Adding transactional method 'OrderProductDAOImpl.addNewOrderProduct' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
[jpa.JpaTransactionManager(doGetTransaction:334)] Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@395dbec7] for JPA transaction
[jpa.JpaTransactionManager(handleExistingTransaction:476)] Participating in existing transaction
[internal.AbstractSaveEventListener(saveWithGeneratedId:130)] Generated identifier: component[orderId,productId]{orderId=144, productId=2553}, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator
[writers.HstsHeaderWriter(writeHeaders:130)] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@1d011fbb
[context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository(saveContext:352)] SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
[internal.SessionImpl(disconnect:566)] Disconnecting session
[internal.LogicalConnectionImpl(releaseConnection:232)] Releasing JDBC connection
[internal.LogicalConnectionImpl(releaseConnection:250)] Released JDBC connection
[jpa.JpaTransactionManager(processRollback:851)] Initiating transaction rollback
[jpa.JpaTransactionManager(doRollback:538)] Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@395dbec7]
[spi.AbstractTransactionImpl(rollback:203)] rolling back
[jdbc.JdbcTransaction(doRollback:164)] rolled JDBC Connection
[jdbc.JdbcTransaction(releaseManagedConnection:126)] re-enabling autocommit
[internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl(close:173)] HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
[jpa.JpaTransactionManager(doCleanupAfterCompletion:600)] Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@395dbec7] after transaction
[jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils(closeEntityManager:435)] Closing JPA EntityManager
[internal.LogicalConnectionImpl(releaseConnection:232)] Releasing JDBC connection
[internal.LogicalConnectionImpl(releaseConnection:250)] Released JDBC connection
```

EDIT:

```
@Controller
public class OrderController {
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    @Transactional
    public void finishPayment(...) {
       //Call to service methods
    }
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class UsersServiceImpl implements UsersService {
    public UsersEntity registerNewGuest(String username, String email, MCountryEntity countryEntity, String nickname, String lang) {
        // Insert User
    }
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class OrderProductServiceImpl implements OrderProductService {
    @Override
    public void addNewOrderProduct(OrderProductEntity orderProductEntity) {
        // Insert OrderProduct
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code also. It seems you have an a `@Transactional` for each of the db insert/update. In that case what you are aiming, wont work

Comment: I added the java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are executing each db insert/update step at each `@Transactional` method. This annotation creates a Db Transaction session at the beggining of execution of that method and commits at the end of the method execution.

Here, each of your db insert is in different database sessions. If you want to roll-back all your db update when a runtime exception occurs, all those transactions should be in same session. But here it's not. This is the cause of your problem.

What you can do is, put all those code, inside a single method annotated with `@Transactional`

I will suggest a pattern..

1. Make a DAO class layer whose methods will *directly connect to database* (hypothetically) and have queries in it. Use `@Repository` to annotate that class.
2. Use the class annotated with `@Service` for your methods with `@Transactional` annotation. So each of those methods will be in **SAME transnational session**. Now you can call, many of your DAO methods in the same service method. If any of those DAO method has Runtime Exception, everything will be rolled back.

**SUMMARY** : Put all db queries during the execution of a single method with `@Transactional`, to automatically roll-back, if Runtime exception occurs.

**Note** : You can put `@Transactional`, method level or class level

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm going to study/develop this solution and if it is correct I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```html
@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

use the above annotation to rollback for any exception